# visual studio publish choosing wrong web.config transform

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013, transform, msdeploy

based on what i read, as long as you have a transform that matches the name of a publish profile, it should be applied, but this is not the case for me.

publish profiles

```
PublisProfiles
    dev.pubxml
    local.pubxml
```

transforms

```
 Web.Config
     Web.Debug.config
     Web.local.config
     Web.Release.config
```

when i publish using **local** config, i see this:

```
Transformed Web.config using  C:\...\Web.Release.config into obj\Release\TransformWebConfig\transformed\Web.config.
```

so it's using Release.config .. i opened up local.pubxml and tried changing this

```
<LastUsedBuildConfiguration>Release</LastUsedBuildConfiguration>
```

to:

```
<LastUsedBuildConfiguration>local</LastUsedBuildConfiguration>
```

but then it's using Web.Debug.config transform.

dev, release, local transforms are identical aside from a few transformed properties ..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

seems like a bug, because i finally got it to work by:

1. delete Web.Debug.config
2. publish local (my Web.local.config is now being applied)
3. right click on Web.Config "Add Config Transform" in order to bring back Web.Debug.config
4. confirmed that the transform still works

Comment: this happened to me again, and this time i resolved it by deleting web.local.config, and going up to properties/publish profiles/local.pubxml > right click > "add config transform" > re-add my changes

Comment: Same here. After removing the transform, I re-added it and made sure it uses the right profile in the configuration manager (it was mixed).

Comment: After updating LastUsedBuildConfiguration, I noticed it kept using the old value.  I simply restarted VIsual Studio and clicked "Preview Transform" again, and it started using the new value.  So... it seems that when you make a change to a pubxml file mnually, it's not detected or used right away.

Answer (score 6):

The publish pipeline should be using *both* your profile's transform and the build configuration transform.

The logic for this is that your profile transform probably has destination-specific settings (e.g. which connection strings to use in Production vs. Staging), but your build configuration has build-specific settings (e.g. Debug has debugging related settings but Release turns them off).  Allowing you to mix and match these gives greater flexibility (need to publish to Staging with debug settings enabled? Just use the Debug build configuration with the Staging profile).  Settings from web.YourProfile.config will always overrule any prior transforms.

Comment: the settings from web.myprofile.config are not being applied.
i see them being applied in transform preview, but not after deploying

Comment: "but your build configuration has build-specific settings (e.g. Debug has debugging related settings but Release turns them off)."   Yeah, that would be cool if Visual Studio actually applied those settings while debugging.  Instead, it applies them only when publishing, so they're actually redundant.  Either both the project configuration and publish transforms are applied (when publish) or they're both NOT applied (while debugging).  The setup is asinine.

Comment: The project configuration transforms should be applied when that configuration is active, while debugging.  The publish profile transforms should be applied in addition to the project configuration transforms when publishing.  As it stands now, they're either both applied or both not applied.  Terrible.

Comment: @Triynko I think most of these concerns are addressed in the new app model for ASP.NET Core.

Comment: More like a jaw-dropping step backwards to how "web site" projects used to work: "In ASP.NET Core the publish process has been simplified, we no longer store a reference to files that the project contains. All files are included in the project by default (files can be excluded from the project or from publish by updating project.json). When you publish an ASP.NET Core project from Visual Studio the following happens."  Absolutely terrible.  Only files explicitly included, with an explicit build option like "None" or "Content" should be published.  Can't believe they went backwards.

Answer (score 4):

My problem with that had to do with the platform configuration:

At the Configuration Manager window, you can choose the config name ("Active solution configuration" combobox) and the target platform ("Active solution platform" combobox). I correctly made the setup of my new configuration ("MyStagingConfig", say) for each project, but forgot about the platform - so I configured it all in "Mixed platform".

When I published the project using "MyStagingConfig - Any CPU", it transformed the config with the  `Web.Staging.config` file, instead of `Web.MyStagingConfig.config`. After a little headache, I realised that the "Any CPU" platform, which I hadn't configured, was configured by default to publish the project with the "Staging" config (as I had imported the settings from the "Staging" config when creating "MyStagingConfig").

Answer (score 2):

In Configuration Manager, check each "Active solution configuration" and make sure the "Configuration" column is correct for each project. (In my case, a developer had accidentally changed one of these values.)

Comment: That's correct! I had "Active solution configuration" as "Staging" but all the configurations below were "Debug". Changing each one to "Staging" did it!

Answer (score 1):

In your csproj you will find code that looks like ...

```
  <Target Name="BeforeBuild" Condition="'$(PublishProfileName)' == '' And '$(WebPublishProfileFile)' == ''">
    <TransformXml Source="Web.config" Transform="Web.$(Configuration).config" Destination="Web.config" />
  </Target>
```

This is the default.  Note, you can modify this, but I am not recommending this.

What I recommend is that you check your build configuration settings.  Select `Build > Configuration Manager` from the menu.  Verify that the configuration selected for your project is the configuration that you want to use.  I.E.  In the second column if you have `Release` selected for your main build project where the web.config is, you will have the `Release` transform even if your solution configuration is titled `Debug`.  Change `Release` to `Debug` (or the appropriate setting) and it will fix your issue.

Answer (score 0):

In VS2015 there is also a bug, but little different: in my case I saw that when I created a new profile on the solution level, it would not be chooseable for the mvc project. It does not even appear in the dropdown.

However, when I clicked New from the mvc project (with checkbox "Create new solutions configuration" checked), only then the new profile would appear with my mvc project.